# Which selenium IDE command should I use to execute a javascript statement

Tags: selenium-ide

I am trying to set a dropdown value using javascript in selenium IDE, but not able to figure out which selenium command to use.

Answer (score 11):

Selenium IDE command to execute a javascript statement: `runScript` with the javascript statement as argument.

Example (can be run on Google startpage):

> ```
> <tr>
>   <td>runScript</td>
>   <td>document.getElementById('searchText').setAttribute("value", "hello");</td>
>   <td></td>
> </tr>
> ```

Comment: That should be accepted answer based on "Which selenium IDE command should I user to execute a javascript statement" title. However description has mention of dropdown and in this particular case there is no need to execute JS but rather use "select" command mentioned by @houss below.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a script (like above) and set the option you want to "selected".

You can also do it with the selenium select command:

```
Command:  select
Target:  id="yourDropDownId"
Value:  label="yourOption"
```

or html source

> ```
> <tr>
>   <td>select</td>
>   <td>id="yourDropDownId"</td>
>   <td>label="yourOption"</td>
> </tr>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dropdown has id `myDropdown` and the value you want to select is `valueToSelect`, try this:

```
selenium.select("//select[@id='myDropdown']", "label=valueToSelect");
```

Comment: Is it applicable for Selenium IDE?