# how to use "mouseDown" command in selenium?

Tags: selenium, mousedown

How to use mouseDown and mouseOver etc in selenium, with the websites I am working click is working but how to use mouse related commands?

Comment: I tried.. but couldn't find anything that clear my doubts properly.. so had to ask here!! Sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use Action Builder

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
```

(for the Mouse Over)
More info [here](http://www.learnseleniumtesting.com/mouse-hover-and-other-mouse-events-in-webdriver/)

With Selenium IDE, you need to execute some javascript code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19985719/709863)

Comment: Thanks a ton..!!

and also I would be really glad to know about how can we use it in IDE..
I want the script to capture, scrolling down a specific page, but while recording(by default) it uses click and therefore captures only elements and not the click on scroll bar to scroll down or scroll up etc.

Comment: For such complex things with Selenium IDE, you will need to execute some javascript code. See here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19985719/709863

Comment: You'r welcome, you should accept answers when they solve your problem

Comment: M pretty new.. Thanks for informing.. i was hunting for that accept button.. :P
finally found it!! :D Thanks!